# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'skip'

Tags: python

```
def intro():

    global skips
    skips = 3
    print ('skip')
    skips = int(input())
    if 'skip' in skips:
        skips - 1
        if skips > 0:
            print('you are out of skips')
            end()
        if skips < 0:
            print ('You have ' ,skips, ' left')

     intro()
def end():
    print ('you are out of skips. Game Over')

intro()
```

I want it too take away (1 *skips*) every time someone types (*skip*).  And every time it runs through the program I want it to check to see if has enough (*skips*).  Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how do you know someone has typed "skip"?

Comment: `skips - 1` does nothing ...

Comment: the error happens because you type "skip" which is read by `input()` and then passed onto `int()` which attempts conversion to integer, and hence raise a `ValueError`

Comment: What do you think `int(input())` is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is closer to what you want:

```
def intro(skips=3):
    print ('skip')
    answer = input()
    if 'skip' in answer:
        skips -= 1
        if skips <= 0:
            print('you are out of skips')
            end()
        elif skips > 0:
            print ('You have ' ,skips, ' left')
            intro(skips)
def end():
    print ('you are out of skips. Game Over')

intro()
```

Comment: Thank you.  It is what I wanted.